# MVC model returns 0s for all properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When passing a model from view to controller-action, all the properties returned are 0s. Please see image attached.
[Returned model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0oWr.jpg)

Action defined in OrderController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(Order_Detail m)
{
    return View();
    //OrderUpdateViewModel model = new OrderUpdateViewModel();
    //model.hasError = true;
    //model.Title = m.OrderDetail.Title + " Edit Status";
}
```

View file Edit.cshtml:

```
@model ADO_Fan.Models.OrderDetailViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDetail.OrderID) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OrderDetail.OrderID)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Product.ProductName)  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Product.ProductName)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDetail.UnitPrice) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OrderDetail.UnitPrice)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Quantity) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Quantity)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Discount) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Discount)<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </div>
}
```

View Model in OrderDetailViewModel.cs

```
using NorthwindDAL;
namespace ADO_Fan.Models
{
    public class OrderDetailViewModel
    {
        public Order_Detail OrderDetail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Order_Detail defined in reference class

```
namespace NorthwindDAL
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("Order Details")]
    public partial class Order_Detail
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

        public short Quantity { get; set; }
        public float Discount { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any advice/suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Because you not generating any inputs for properties other than `OrderDetail.Quantity`. (a form only posts back the name/value pairs of successful form controls, and `DisplayFor()` does not generate a form control).

Comment: And the model in your view is `OrderDetailViewModel` so the parameter in the POST method needs to be the same - `public ActionResult Update(OrderDetailViewModel m)` - but a view model should never contain a property which is a data model - refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: Thanks Stephen! You were absolutely right about both issues.

Answer (score 0):

you have to understand `LabelFor` and `DisplayFor` does only one way trip means they will only display the data and do not return data on submit so you can either user 
`TextBoxFor` for returning the data or you can use `HiddenFor` like

```
@model ADO_Fan.Models.OrderDetailViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderDetail.OrderID);
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Product.ProductName);
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderDetail.UnitPrice);
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Quantity);
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Discount);

    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDetail.OrderID) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OrderDetail.OrderID)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Product.ProductName)  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Product.ProductName)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDetail.UnitPrice) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OrderDetail.UnitPrice)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Quantity) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Quantity)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Discount) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OrderDetail.Discount)<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </div>
}
```

or you can change `@Html.LabelFor` to   `@Html.TextBoxFor`

Comment: Thanks Usman! You were right about the Html.LabelFor and Html.TextBoxFor. I also had a problem with the parameter type in my POST action as Stephen pointed out above. My first MVC project. Thanks for the input!!!

Comment: you can accept answer if it helped. if you dont know how you can check this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work